# Tekerik radwindow open and close issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-mvc

With the click event of a link button calling a server side method from Form1

**Form1 aspx.cs page code:-**

```
protected void lnkTakeAction_OnCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {

         if (e.CommandName == "duplicate")
        {
            //Some operations conditional
            //If condition true
            //call javascript method to call a javascript function to open a rad window
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,     typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "ABC "ABCPopUp" + ID + "','Tag');", true);

        }
    }
```

Form1 aspx javascript code:-

```
function ABCPopUp(ID, Tag) {

                    var oWindow = window.radopen('XYZPage.aspx?ID=' + scoreMethodId + '&Tag=' + mode, 'rdWindowMapping');
                    oWindow.SetSize(600, 500);
                    oWindow.Center();
                    var titleBar = oWindow.GetTitlebar();
                    $telerik.$(titleBar).parent().hide();

            return false;
        }
```

Issue facing - The XYZPage is not opening.The same functionality works if I  call the function ABCPopUp from javascript.But when I call from server side the form is not opening.Please give expert advice

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the script runs too early. You have two options:

- use AJAX for the grid and do not include the RadWindow in the response
- OR, use the Sys.Application.Load event to call your function: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-troubleshooting-opening-from-server.html.